# Keep getting "MySQL has gone away" and "Error while sending QUERY packet"

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, wordpress

### Explanation

There is a single wordpress website on a XEN VPS with CentOS (2GB RAM, 2 cores) with average visitors which was previously working on a cheap shared hosting without this kind of issues (transferred for other reasons).

- 132 tables in database
- Total database size 40MB
- Largest table is 22MB, 5000 rows
- Mostly (96%) `select` queries, average is 200k `select` queries per hour.

MySQL Network traffic:

```
----------------------------------
|    Traffic     |     per hour  |
----------------------------------
|   Received     |    64.6 MiB   |
|    Sent        |     1.5 GiB   |
|    Total       |     1.5 GiB   |
----------------------------------
```

`free -m` result:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1868       1636        232          4         32       1113
-/+ buffers/cache:        490       1378 
Swap:         1023         57        966
```

---

### Issue

> Keep getting two errors every 4-5 hours like this:
>
> 1. Lots (20-40) of this error: `Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=XXXX in ...wp-db.php on line 1942`
> 2. Some (3-5) of this error: `mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in ...`

This happens for a few seconds or mostly 5 min, and then no errors at all for another 4-5 hours.

---

### What I've done

As I understood this is related to `max_allowed_packet` , so I tried values from 256M to 900M without any success, also modified some other configs but reverted back after.

Current `my.cnf` file is as below (it was empty when the issue started happening):

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=524288000
open_files_limit=15000
wait_timeout=70
connect_timeout=70
```

---

Any suggestions or help is really appreciated.

Comment: Look in your logs to see if there is more, relevant information.

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: What is the result of SELECT @@flush_timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size per [this thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-server-stops-very-frequently?comment=42488).  That has helped me out in the past.